# startService() throws java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

From `onCreate()` of my Activity,

I am trying to start a service via following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName(SERVICE_PKG_NAME, SERVICE_NAME);
context.startService(intent); //context = MainActivity.this
```

However, I receive following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent (service-name) : app is in background

Any idea what could be reason for this? Stuck on it for few hours now.

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on? Also, can you post the entire Java stack trace?

Comment: Does it work with `getApplicationContext().startService(intent)`?

Comment: @tynn No tried it..still the same error..

Comment: @CommonsWare Android -O. From https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html  seems newly added. **bold** The startService() method now throws an IllegalStateException if an app targeting Android O tries to use that method in a situation when it isn't permitted to create background services.**bold**

Comment: Your error message matched what I was seeing from O, which is why I was asking about the device version. Where and when are you trying to start the service?

Comment: @CommonsWare **Problem Scenario**: My App A tries to start service & bind to it (of App B). However , App B is in background & App A is in foreground, so system won't allow to start Service for app in Background.    **Solution** Able to fix  by Starting the service of App B on boot-up (by listen to boot complete receiver). Then App A is able to bind succcessfully.  Ofcourse Limitation of this solution is start service at boot-up & not when required.   Any other **suggestions** to avoid this limitation

Comment: "so system won't allow to start Service for app in Background" -- that does not make any sense. App A is in the foreground. It is supposed to be able to start services to its heart's content, including any services of App B. Regardless, try binding to the service first, then calling `startService()` for that same service once the service is bound.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, your suggestion works fine.   Only call bindService() first, after OnServiceConnected() due to bind call, call StartService(). Could you explain the rationale why this sequence works fine but the original one didn't ?

Comment: Perhaps it is a bug in Android O. Otherwise, given your description of the symptoms, I have no idea why it would behave that way.

Comment: @CommonsWare I was able to solve this problem as I mentioned before by calling bindService() followed by startService(). However it was applicable only when App A was in foreground. Now I have another scenario where App C (a Background service) want to startService() of App B, but crashes even when call startService() from onServiceConnected() [of bindService]. Any suggestions for this scenario ?

Comment: Perhaps A, B, and C should all be one app. Regardless, you can try calling `startForegroundService()` on `Context` instead of `startService()`.

Comment: if you're using `IntentService` switching to  `JobIntentService` should do the trick. Under the hood it's using `JobScheduler` for Devices running O+ and `IntentService` for older APIs

Comment: @SahilMehta : try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445265/android-8-0-java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-inten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For cases involving need to invoke service of Background app from a foreground app, We can follow the sequence:

- call bindService() first
- after OnServiceConnected() due to bind call
- call StartService().

Comment: So this has to be a Bound Service?

Comment: So how do I start a service in reaction to a Firebase Notification?

Comment: @DanielF I think it's better to use JobScheduler for it. You can specify the Job to be started to it, based on certain condition like Charger Connected etc. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html

Comment: @SahilMehta Thanks for your feedback. My issue was that I started targeting API 26 and there you can't invoke a service from the background unless you do it with `startForegroundService` (I think that was the name), You have to pass it a notification then.

Comment: @DanielF ,I think JobScheduler should help in this case. I had a similar scenario.